# Removing dynamically created lines in table

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table

I have a table into which I am dynamically adding new lines.
With a line added it looks like this:

```
<table>
<tbody id="list">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="new1">                           //
    <td class="new1">D</td>                   //
    <td class="new1">E</td>                   //  These lines
    <td class="new1">                         //  are dynamic
      <a href="#confirm" class="new1">X</a>   //
    </td>                                     //
  </tr>                                       //
</body>
</table>
```

I want to be able to delete new lines individually by clicking X symbol in last column, which redirects me to dialog to confirm that.
Dialog is simple - two buttons: yes/no.

My idea is to get class of clicked a element, save it as variable and then use it when clicking yes button to delete all elements with that particular class.

Script I made looks like this:

```
// For saving class of clicked link in list
var delId;
$(document).on("click", "#list a", function(){
  delId= $(this).attr("class");
});

// Then I try to remove elements by class
$("#idOfYesButton").click(function(){
    $("."+delId).remove();
});
```

But it somehow does nothing and I can't figure why, so if you could tell me where I did wrong it would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: `</body>` should be `</tbody>`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r9pbj2bd/3/. Is your `#idOfYesButton` handler inside `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvm8hhLg/)

```
<table>
    <tr class="new1">
        <td class="new1">D</td>
        <td class="new1">E</td>
        <td class="new1"> <a href="#" class="remove">X</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new1">
        <td class="new1">D</td>
        <td class="new1">E</td>
        <td class="new1"> <a href="#" class="remove">X</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new1">
        <td class="new1">D</td>
        <td class="new1">E</td>
        <td class="new1"> <a href="#" class="remove">X</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(".remove").click(function () {
    if (confirm("sure you want to delete?") === true) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
    else return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
$(document).on("click", "#list tr td a", function(){
  if(confirm($(this).attr("class")))
        $("."+$(this).attr("class")).remove();
});
```